# Add new columns from a list based on the values in existing column, may be with for loop

Tags: python, pandas

```
                    OBJECT        STATE  SM4         
TIMESTAMP                                            
2017-10-31 11:09:09    SM4     Movement             1
2017-10-31 11:09:10    SM4     Movement             1
2017-10-31 11:09:11    SM4  No movement             0
2017-10-31 11:09:12    SM4  No movement             0
2017-10-31 11:09:13    SM4  No movement             0
2017-10-31 11:09:14    SM4  No movement             0
2017-10-31 11:09:15    SM4  No movement             0
2017-10-31 11:29:42    M01         Open             0
2017-10-31 11:29:43    M01         Open             0
2017-10-31 11:29:44    M01        Close             0
```

`TIMESTAMP` column is index. `OBJECT`, `STATE`, and `SM4` are columns. I have added a new column `SM4` using the following code. It adds value `1`, if `STATE` is equal to `Movement`, and `0` otherwise for object `SM4`.

```
df['SM4'] = df.OBJECT.str.contains('SM4').astype(int) & df.STATE.str.contains('Movement').astype(int)
```

Now, in `OBJECT` column I have 14 unique sensors: `'SM4', 'C14', 'SM3', 'M01', 'D07', 'C10', 'C08', 'C09', 'SM1', 'D10', 'D01', 'D02', 'D03', 'C12'`.

I want to do the same for all sensors automatically instead manually creating each column may be with a loop, for some sensors, the state is `Open` or `Pressure` instead of `Movement`.

How I can do that in a loop, so that all columns added automatically based on the condition in my code?

Comment: Are you using some sort of database or framework beyond the Python standard library? What kind of object is df?

Answer (score 0):

I assume my example data frame, called `df`, looks like this:

```
  OBJECT        STATE
0    SM4     Movement
1    SM4     Movement
2    SM4  No movement
3    SM4  No movement
4    SM4  No movement
5    SM4  No movement
6    SM4  No movement
7    M01         Open
8    M01         Open
9    M01        Close
```

You can iterate over unique values in `OBJECT` column and make a new column based on condition like this:

```
for obj in df['OBJECT'].unique():
    condition = (df['OBJECT']==obj) & (df['STATE'].isin(['Movement', 'Open', 'Pressure']))
    df[obj] = np.where(condition, 1, 0)
```

The result is following:

```
  OBJECT        STATE  SM4  M01
0    SM4     Movement    1    0
1    SM4     Movement    1    0
2    SM4  No movement    0    0
3    SM4  No movement    0    0
4    SM4  No movement    0    0
5    SM4  No movement    0    0
6    SM4  No movement    0    0
7    M01         Open    0    1
8    M01         Open    0    1
9    M01        Close    0    0
```